# Laravel seed issue

Tags: php, laravel, seed

I recently took over a Laravel project & I'm new to the framework. It looks like I have everything setup but I get the error below when I try to seed the database.

A few tables do get seeded and then I get the error.

Is there something I'm missing here?

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'App\Database\Seeder\Local\Encrypter' not found
```

Thanks

Comment: please paste full seeder file

Comment: Find the seeder that's calling an `Encrypter` class and show us the code. Likely a namespacing issue.

Comment: can you try php artisan key:generate command